# Adding Ionic Components

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to have a default segment active in my app. I referred other threads and questions and the solution seems to be  be doing some changes in the segment js present in the components folder.

But I don't have  any segment file inside the component folder. I have been just typing the code in the html pages to add the component.

Have I been doing it wrong? Or is there any way to add it?

Thanks for you help.

**Edit 1:**

```
<div>
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="testing">
    <ion-segment-button value="book">book</ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="table">table</ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</div>
  <div [ngSwitch]="testing" >
    <ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'book'" ngSelected="selected">
      <a ion-item>
        <ion-label>book list</ion-label>
      </a>
   </ion-list>
<ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'table'">
      <a ion-item>
        <ion-label>table list</ion-label>
      </a>
   </ion-list>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please add the most relevant parts of your code to the question?

Comment: can you add some code to try help you as @sebaferreras said?

Comment: code added in edit 1.

Comment: where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the first tab by default, you could assign the value of the segment to the `testing` property when you declare it:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public testing = 'book';

  // ...

}
```

And then in the view:

```
<div>
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="testing">
    <ion-segment-button value="book">book</ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="table">table</ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</div>
  <div [ngSwitch]="testing" >
    <ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'book'"> <!-- I've removed the ngSelected-->
      <a ion-item>
        <ion-label>book list</ion-label>
      </a>
   </ion-list>
<ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'table'">
      <a ion-item>
        <ion-label>table list</ion-label>
      </a>
   </ion-list>
</div>
```

The explanation is quite simple. `<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="testing">` binds the segment component to the `testing` property, and `<div [ngSwitch]="testing" >` will check the value of the `testing` property to see what list should be shown:

`<ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'book'">...</ion-list>` or `<ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'table'">...</ion-list>`

So by assigning the `'book'` value to the `testing` property from your component, you'll select the first segment by default.

If you want to change the selected tab (programmatically), you can just do `this.testing = 'table';` and the second segment will be selected.